# "iwlist scan" returns "Interface doesn't support scanning"

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I have used a Git project that builds `iwlist` and couple of other wireless program on Android. When I try to run `iwlist scan` on Yellowstone, it returns

```
rmnetctl Interface doesn't support scanning.
wlan0 Interface doesn't support scanning.
sit0 Interface doesn't support scanning.
dummy0 Interface doesn't support scanning.
rmnet0 Interface doesn't support scanning.
lo Interface doesn't support scanning.
ip6tnl0 Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

which means, basically all of the interface doesn't support scanning.

When I execute `iwconfig` on the device, it returns

```
wlan0 no wireless extensions.
```

I try to use `netcfg` for `wlan0`, but the output shows it's indeed up and there is IP address assigned for the device. And strange is, if I run the same program on the Peanut, there is indeed an output and WIFI signal can be captured successfully. Is there a solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Is this the [github project](https://github.com/nvamelichev/wireless-tools-android) you are referring to? Are you running it as root? If you have a tablet, you shouldn't have the root permission to run this.. Also, another thing worth to check is the build target, see if it's on 19..

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/nvamelichev/wireless-tools-android/blob/master/iwlist.c#L741) of the iwlist.c. It looks like the function call requires some permission to execute. Since Tango is on user build, which is not allow root permission, so this might not work on the device? This is just my guess..